# How can I change a struct variable in a function using threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

I want to change the struct variable in the thread function as global.

But this doesn't work:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 1

typedef struct {
  int id;
  int reservable;
} Customer;

void *CustomerFunc(void *customer) {
  Customer *a;
  a = (Customer *)customer;
  printf("reservable %d", a->reservable);
  a->reservable = 5;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pthread_t abc[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc; 
  long t;
  Customer *customer = (Customer*)malloc(sizeof(Customer));
  customer->id = 1;
  customer->reservable = 2;
  rc = pthread_create(&abc[0], NULL, CustomerFunc, (void *)&customer);
  printf("reservable MAIN%d", customer->reservable);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This code result is:

```
reservable: 0 reservable MAIN: 2
```

But I want to see:

```
reservable: 2 reservable MAIN: 5
```

Comment: `(void *)&customer` is a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Also, `CustomerFunc` should return a value.

Comment: Also, you should wait for the thread to complete before trying to print the result.

Comment: but i dont want this func to return value @JohnnyMopp

Comment: The function prototype says it should return a `void *`. If you don't want to return anything, change to `void CustomerFunc(void *customer) {`.

Comment: okey, can we think about the main problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple issues to resolve:

1. You have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) between the `main` and the worker thread on the `customer` struct. The threads rush in at the same time trying to access the `reservable` field and it's non-deterministic as to which thread makes it there first.

   One option is to make the `main` thread wait for the worker thread to finish (using [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)) before attempting to print the updated value, or use a conditional construct like a semaphore to ensure ordering (depending on your application goals). Always `detach` or `join` your threads.
2. `customer` is already a pointer, so you can just pass it into the worker function as-is, without taking the address using `&`, which makes its type `Customer **`. Had you allocated `customer` on the local function stack rather than the heap, it'd be appropriate to use `&`.

...and a few less critical suggestions...

3. Remember to free `customer`'s memory to avoid a leak.
4. Return a `void *` value from the worker function.
5. `abc` is a confusing variable name--`threads` is more accurate. Same for `t`, `rc` and `a`.
6. [No need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to cast the return value of `malloc`.
7. Check the return value of `malloc` (skipped in my code below for brevity).

Here's an updated version:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 1

typedef struct {
    int id;
    int reservable;
} Customer;

void *customerFunc(void *arg) {
    Customer *customer = (Customer *)arg;
    printf("reservable %d\n", customer->reservable);
    customer->reservable = 5;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    Customer *customer = malloc(sizeof(*customer));
    customer->id = 1;
    customer->reservable = 2;

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, customerFunc, customer);
    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);

    printf("reservable MAIN %d\n", customer->reservable);
    free(customer);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
reservable 2
reservable MAIN 5
```

Comment: Re, "...You could also use a mutex lock for this..." That makes it sound as if using the mutex would somehow ensure that the threads access the variable in the right order. But a mutex alone can never do that. Wrapping the shared variable access in a mutex would ensure that both threads see a consistent view of the shared data, but the outcome of the program still would depend on a race: It would depend on which thread won the race to lock the mutex.

Comment: That's a good point, mutex isn't going to ensure ordering without a condition variable or semaphore. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new thread, it runs independently of the main thread.  This means that nothing is stopping the `printf` in `main` from executing before `CustomerFunc` makes any change.

A simple way to fix this is for the main thread to wait until the new thread finishes by calling `pthread_join`.

You're also not passing `customer` to `pthread_create` properly.  `&customer` has type `Customer **` but your thread function is expecting a `Customer *`, so remove the address-of operator `&`.

```
rc = pthread_create(&abc[0],NULL,CustomerFunc, customer);
pthread_join(abc[0], NULL);

printf("reservable MAIN%d", customer->reservable);
```